# PyQt5 installation error (QtCore Module Error: Unable to create the C++ code)

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5, python-sip

I'm trying to install PyQt5 on my PC to have access to QtDesigner.

I'm facing following error during the installation:

```
$ python3 configure.py --qmake=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.10.1/bin/qmake --sip=/usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.19.8_2/bin/sip
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...
This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.7 (licensed under the GNU General Public License) for Python 3.6.3 on darwin.

......
DBus v1 does not seem to be installed.
Qt v5.10.1 is being used.
The qmake executable is /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.10.1/bin/qmake.
Qt is built as a shared library.
SIP 4.19.8 is being used.
The sip executable is /usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.19.8_2/bin/sip.
The PyQt5 Python package will be installed in
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages.
PyQt5 is being built with generated docstrings.
PyQt5 is being built with 'protected' redefined as 'public'.
The Designer plugin will be installed in
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.10.1/plugins/designer.
The qmlscene plugin will be installed in
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.10.1/plugins/PyQt5.
The PyQt5 PEP 484 stub files will be installed in
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5.
The PyQt5 .sip files will be installed in
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/share/sip/PyQt5.
pyuic5, pyrcc5 and pylupdate5 will be installed in
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin.
The interpreter used by pyuic5 is python3.6.
Generating the C++ source for the QtCore module...
Error: Unable to create the C++ code.
```

Installation Environment:

macOS Sierra (version 10.12.6)

PyQt5 GPL 5.7

Qt 5.10

SIP 4.19.8

Two python versions, tried with both versions but same problem.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.14

$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.3
```

Followed readme instructions for the installation:
Installed Qt using following:

```
$ brew install qt
Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Sierra.
Install the Command Line Tools:
 xcode-select --install

$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools

$ brew install qt
Updating Homebrew...
==> Summary /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.10.1: 9,375 files, 295.2MB
```

Then installed SIP using following:

```
$brew install sip
==> Installing dependencies for sip: gdbm, openssl, readline, sqlite, xz, python, python@2
==> Summary /usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.19.8_2: 16 files, 1.1MB
```

Update:
Using --verbose option with configure command:

```
Generating the C++ source for the QtCore module...
/usr/local/Cellar/sip/4.19.8_2/bin/sip -w -f -t WS_MACX -t Qt_5_10_1 -B Qt_6_0_0 -P -o -y QtCore.pyi -c /Users/apple/Desktop/Python/PyQt5_gpl-5.7/QtCore -I sip -I /Users/apple/Desktop/Python/PyQt5_gpl-5.7/sip /Users/apple/Desktop/Python/PyQt5_gpl-5.7/sip/QtCore/QtCoremod.sip
sip: Deprecation warning: /Users/apple/Desktop/Python/PyQt5_gpl-5.7/sip/QtCore/QtCoremod.sip:23: %Module version numbers are deprecated and ignored
Error: Unable to create the C++ code.
```

Please advise how to solve this error.

Appreciate your support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to sort it out, the issue was related to the used SIP version.

I used SIP version compatible with PyQt5 5.7 which is SIP 4.18.1 and the problem was solved.

Next step:

```
$make
```

I faced another issue:

```
error: 'WindowOkButtonHint' : is not a member of 'Qt'
error: 'WindowCancelButtonHint' : is not a member of 'Qt'
```

To solve this I edited the ~/QtCore/sipQtCoreQt.cpp file and removed the 2 problematic lines.

http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/720187/

Comment: Thanks for a SIP version note, managed to overlook that in my case.

Comment: For PyQt5 5.15.12, `pip install sip==5.5.0` seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the advice from @armyoung above, and it worked out. :)

The exact way to modify configure_ng.py is to find and delete (or comment out) these two lines:

```
argv.append('-B') 
argv.append('Qt_5_0_0')
```

Answer (score 1):

same problem!

first:

sudo python configure_ng.py --verbose

--verbose args to see more details

then it shows:

for sip -B not support

so i modify configure_ng.py

Comment: Please add more information to your answer as how do you modify `configure_ng.py` for example. This is very low quality answer consider that the question already answered by the OP author.