# How to install PyQtWebEngine in MSYS2 (Windows 10)

Tags: python, pyqt5, msys2, qtwebengine

Well, first of all i try to install PyQtWebEngine with pip:

`pip install PyQtWebEngine`

but it fails.

Then i downloaded the PyQtWebEngine source code [from here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/5d/4c5bb7adca4f2436545a391fe311dcb4ccc711f1ce2ab7adb87475ec566e/PyQtWebEngine-5.15.4.tar.gz).

After that, i install sip with pacman command:

`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sip4`

After that i cd to the source downloaded of PyQtWebEngine, and finally i run:

`python configure.py --sip /c/msys64/mingw64/bin/sip.exe --qmake /c/msys64/mingw64/bin/qmake.exe` from msys2 mingw64 console.

Output:

```
Configuring PyQtWebEngine 5.15.2...
The PyQtWebEngine .sip files will be installed in
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/bindings.
PyQtWebEngine will be installed in
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5.
PyQt 5.15.4 is being used.
Qt 5.15.2 is being used.
sip 4.19.25 is being used.
The sip executable is C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/sip.exe.
The PEP 484 stubs will be installed in
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5.
The QScintilla API file will be installed in
C:/msys64/mingw64/share/qt5/qsci/api/python.
Generating the C++ source for the QtWebEngine module...
Error: Unable to create the C++ code.
```

I search for this error (Generating the C++ source for the QtWebEngine module...
Error: Unable to create the C++ code.), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585442/pyqt5-installation-error-qtcore-module-error-unable-to-create-the-c-code) has answer related to sip version.

So the Question is, how can i install PyQtWebEngine (PyQt 5.15.2) in MSYS2?

Note: I read in qt forum that is not possible, but i want this module to display some chat iframes in the main pyqt5 program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the difference of PyQtWebEngine and PyQtWebKit, but [this package](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-qtwebkit), is only what i need.